# I am trying to check a website status if its online or not

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpresponse, httpurlconnection

I am working on an app which connect to a website and grab some data from it.The problem I am having is when I try to check if the website is live or not via **HttpURLConnection** but its says the website is offline mostly. When I access the website from the phone browser website is working. Sometimes when I first open the app it's says website offline but when I close the app and opens it again, it connect mostly. I am checking the website **response time** if it's equal to **200** then website is live but I don't know what's going wrong.I used thread to give some delay to the **asynctask** but still its not working perfect.

Here is the code.

```
package com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Splash_Activity extends Activity implements Animation.AnimationListener {

    UserSessionManager session;
    Data data;
    ProgressWheel progress;

    boolean check;
    String url = "";

    FileInputStream inputStream;
    String filename = "newMyProfileData";
    Animation animFadein;
    Animation animFadeout;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        boolean finish = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("finish", false);
        if (finish) {

            finish();
            return;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.splast_activty);


        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);

        progress = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

        url = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_URL);

        animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.blink);
        animFadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.fade_out);
        animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);
        animFadeout.setAnimationListener(this);

        animFadein.setDuration(1300);
        animFadeout.setDuration(1000);
        animFadeout.setStartOffset(1200 + animFadein.getStartOffset() + 1200);


        data = new Data(getApplicationContext());

        progress.spin();

        if(animFadein!=null)
        {
            linearLayout.startAnimation(animFadein);

        }

        if (!session.checkLogin() && isOnline()) {

            final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
            handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new checkingnetwork().execute();
                }
            }, 2000);


            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getcheck();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
        else if (!session.checkLogin() && !isOnline()) {

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getcheck();
                }
            }, 4000);

        } else {
            getcheck();
        }
    }

public class checkingnetwork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                // FIRST METHOD I TRIED
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url).openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                check = (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);

                // SECOND METHOD I TRIED
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                check =  (200 <= responseCode && responseCode <= 399);

                System.out.print(responseCode);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
    }

}
```

and here is the logcat

```
1-11 23:04:24.804 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: SBServiceAPI: getService class android.os.ServiceManager
01-11 23:04:24.804 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
01-11 23:04:24.804 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-18855-353874012: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
01-11 23:04:26.204 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
01-11 23:04:27.824 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal time:27606813
01-11 23:04:27.984 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/debug: Screen inches : 5.2007338145504045
01-11 23:04:27.994 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
01-11 23:04:28.024 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable/header.jpg
01-11 23:04:28.114 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/profile_picture.png
01-11 23:04:28.204 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
01-11 23:04:28.204 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
01-11 23:04:28.234 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/tick_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.234 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/time_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.234 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/result_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.274 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-11 23:04:28.294 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-11 23:04:28.324 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-11 23:04:28.334 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-11 23:04:28.484 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/profile_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.484 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/progress_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.484 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/notification_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.494 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/eva.png
01-11 23:04:28.494 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/password_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.504 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/feedback_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.514 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/privacy_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.524 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{3bfd695e V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0d01ad app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass
01-11 23:04:28.524 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{1db4b13f V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d01ad app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass
01-11 23:04:28.524 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{9aada0c V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d01ad app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass
01-11 23:04:28.644 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@12a519a2 time:27607635
01-11 23:04:28.644 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@29c55571 time:27607635
01-11 23:04:30.024 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:116)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:150)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:97)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:198)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:119)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:777)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal.Splash_Activity$checkingnetwork.doInBackground(Splash_Activity.java:223)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal.Splash_Activity$checkingnetwork.doInBackground(Splash_Activity.java:208)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-11 23:05:00.344 10320-10351/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/art: Debugger is no longer active
01-11 23:05:00.644 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
01-11 23:06:03.744 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@12a519a2 time:27702733
```

I have tried everything to make it work but I don't know what I am doing wrong. It would be really helpful if you guy help me solve this problem.

Comment: as you can see in the error logs you are getting : java.net.SocketTimeoutException
which means that your code was not able to connect to the server in the time limit that you had set. How long does the website take to load on the browser usually ?

Comment: @Kakarot usually it takes around 1 sec or 2 max if the network is slow

Comment: if you get status code in the series of 4xx then we can say site is offline for eg.404 error.

Comment: @dullpointer I tried the second method mentioned in the to check if the status code is in between 200 to 400 then the site isn't offline but it doesn't work either

Comment: About the second method. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html  The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. Could you please try with *GET* instead of *HEAD*  And please increase timeouts and don't forget that url have to be with protocol

Comment: what response code are you getting back ?

Comment: @Kakarot when it can't connect the response code is null and the socket exception occurs.

Comment: @AndreyICE I tried to use **GET** instead of **HEAD** but same thing happening again. First time it's says website is offline but next time it connects to  it.

Comment: Have you tried to copy url and open it in Chrome? Or you are using no HTTP  protocol ?

Comment: @AndreyICE yes I have tried to open it in chrome when it's say website is offline both in mobile browser and desktop browser.

Comment: So looks like you site is really offline)   add check = false to catch block

Comment: @AndreyICE here is the website [link](http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tryed

```
package gorand.com.myapplication111;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final CheckingSiteResponse task = new CheckingSiteResponse("http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/");
            task.execute();

        }
    });
}

public class CheckingSiteResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mUrl;

    CheckingSiteResponse(String url) {
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Boolean result = false;

        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(mUrl).openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            result = (200 >= responseCode && responseCode <= 399);

            Log.e("TAG", "RESPONCE = " + responseCode);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ONLINE = " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

and it's works fine.
Don't forget to include

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to *AndroidManifest.xml*